# Set Excel data connection (csv) with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for a solution to the following problem, but haven't found anything that was really helpful: I have an excel sheet with data connections to a number of csv. Sadly, excel does save the connection as absolute paths. Ideally I would be able to set the path as relative paths, but I would settle for a macro that would allow the user to update the connections depending on `thisworkbook.path` before first use.

The project is in a folder d:\project with the excel sheet in d:\project\excel and the csv in d:\project\results. If I would send the project as a zip to some user, and he unzips into c:\my documents\project he will have to reconnect the 10 or so csv.

My general idea would be to write a macro along the lines of (no real code, since I'm new to vba, and if I knew the code, I wouldn't have to ask)

```
filepath = thisworkbook.path
cons = thisworkbook.connections
for each cons
   filename = cons.filename
   newpath = filepath & filename
end for
```

Comment: @ enderland: see revised question.

Comment: From what I know, there is no easy way to just change the path of a data connection. One way to do is to loop through all the connections in your workbook, delete them, and then build new ones to the same files in the new path. I would think you would have to set up a mapping that told you which connections went into which cells. That said, to get your started, turn on the macro recorder before manually setting up a connection. Once you have that code down, you can use variables and loops to set up all your connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I've been searching for the same thing now and I just finally figured this out.   Maybe someone else has said the same, but I haven't found it by searching the Googles...

Lets say you already have these conditions:

1. You already have a data connection set up in a work book (let say it's name is MyData in the connection manager
2. The destination of the data connection is already defined and is some location in Sheet1
3. You have a cell (Say A1 of Sheet2) that has the file name you want to connect to
4. You just need to change the path that the connection is looking so that it follows the path of the work book

If this is the case, something like this should do the trick.

```
Dim fileLoc As String
Dim fileName As String

fileLoc = ThisWorkbook.Path
fileName = Sheet2.Range("A1").Value

Dim conString As String
conString = "TEXT;" & fileLoc & "\" & fileName

Sheet1.QueryTables.Item("MyData").Connection = conString
```

Feel free to modify or tweek that as your case necessitates.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the connection path like this

```
Sub UpdateConnections()
    Dim con As WorkbookConnection
    Dim ConString As String
    For Each con In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        ConString = con.Ranges.Item(1).QueryTable.Connection
        ' Path update code here
    Next
End Sub
```

For a Text data source returns a string like `"TEXT;C:\My\Path\Documents\FileName.csv"`

While testing this I found that changing the path also affected some other properties so you will probably need to reset a bunch of properties after changing the path.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, the following is what I came up with in the end:

```
Sub UpdateAllConnections()

    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Delete
    Next cn

    Dim arrConNames(1) As String
    Dim arrSheetNames(1) As String
    arrConNames(0) = "test1.csv"
    arrConNames(1) = "test2.csv"
    arrSheetNames(0) = "test1"
    arrSheetNames(1) = "test2"

    Dim indCon As Integer

    For indCon = LBound(arrSheetNames) To UBound(arrSheetNames)
        UpdateConnections arrConNames(indCon), arrSheetNames(indCon)
    Next
End Sub

Sub UpdateConnections(ConName As String, SheetName As String)
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    ResultPath = Replace(FilePath, "Excel-Shell", "Results")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & ResultPath & "\" & ConName, Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = ConName
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```